# Не вставляется слайдер

Tags: css3, slider, html

http://jsfiddle.net/9scz6qnw/

Comment: Вставляется, вот же он, с неподгруженными картинками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две версии jQuery подгружается:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

А вот JS файла для слайдера не видать.